# using mule variable value in xpath expression

Tags: xpath, expression, mule, mule-studio

I have a variable set as

```
<set-variable variableName="productIdvar" value="#[xpath://productId]" doc:name="Variable" />
```

On logging its coming right,

I want to use the value of the variable productIdvar in my xpath expression,

```
<when expression="//*[local-name()='itemid']=?" evaluator="xpath">
```

or

```
<when expression="#[xpath://*[local-name()='itemid']=?]">
```

What should i use in place of ? to get the value of the variable?

Thanks
Rahul.

Answer (score 2):

The following expression should work for you.

```
<when expression="#[xpath('//*[local-name()=\'itemid\']').text == productIdvar ]">
```

This way you should be able to compare the result of the xpath with the "productIdVar"  variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'productIdvar' is a DOM text node too so why not: `productIdvar.text`?

Comment: @David Dossot as per the config code provided in the OP, productIdVar is String [xpath://productId] . If it was xpath('//productId') then I should have used productIdVar.text

Comment: You are correct: I didn't realize the OP was using the deprecated expression syntax to set `productIdvar`, I wrongly assumed it was MEL :$

Comment: @user1760178 :thanks for your replies but using the above answer i am getting the following error-    Caused by:    org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "xpath('//*[local-name()=\'itemid\']').text == productIdvar" failed.

Comment: @DavidDossot: i even used productIdvar.text it gave the same exception.

Comment: I worked it out somehow i saved the xpath expression as a string, like <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation">
                     <add-message-property key="xpathexpression" value="#[string://*[local-name()='itemid']=#[variable:productIdvar]]" /> </message-properties-transformer> and used it as <when expression="'#[header:Invocation:xpathexpression]'" evaluator="xpath"> but i would really like to know a way to use the variable in xpath expressions as it will be useful for other xpath expressions i have where i have to set a new variable as dynamic xpath exp. Thanks

Comment: What Mule version are you using? You're using the deprecated expression syntax that has been replaced by MEL since 3.3.0.

Comment: @DavidDossot I realized that and i am now trying to move to the latest version.Thanks for your input.Its been a year since i worked on mule :|.

Answer (score 0):

```
<when expression="#[xpath('//*[local-name()=itemid]') == productIdvar ]">
```

Note that there are no quotation marks surrounding `itemid` in expression

Answer (score 0):

If your MEL gets a bit messy, try my [mule-module-dxpath](https://github.com/skjolber/mule-module-dxpath) - an XPath transformer which dynamicaly resolves XPath variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH3 and try something like this
`#[xpath3('/products/validlity')== flowVars.productIdvar]`
Xpath3 reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XPath