# Using a mule variable value inside an xpath expression to query a repeating XML node

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

Lets set the example XML as:

```
<test>
    <randomtag>abc</randomtag>
    <person>
        <name>john</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>peter</name>
    </person>
</test>
```

**Goal:**
I want to use the Mule `ForEach` component to call a logger to output as follows: 
john
peter

The Xpath that is required is as follows:

`#[xpath("//person[1]/name/text()")]` for john

`#[xpath("//person[2]/name/text()")]` for peter

**Question:** How do I make the values of the indexes `1` & `2` dynamic?

I was trying something like:
`#[xpath("//person[flowVars.forEachCounterVariable]/name/text()")]` but did not work.

PS: Similar but not the same: [using mule variable value in xpath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010219/using-mule-variable-value-in-xpath-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concatenate it like a string...

**#[xpath('//person['+flowVars.forEachCounterVariable+']/name/text()')]**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :-

```
 <splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/test" doc:name="Splitter_For_MultipleSameNodes"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <foreach collection="#[xpath('//test')]" doc:name="For Each">
    <logger message="ID:- #[xpath('person/name/text()')] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     </foreach>
```

Comment: Thank you Anirban - appreciate the input

Comment: Quick Question: Why did you use the <splitter> upfront and not go straight into the the <forEach>

Comment: You used the Splitter to 'split' on /test - which is the root node... what is the reasoning behind this?